# Soldering Header Pins Together to Multiplex Single Digit 7-Segment Displays

Tags: multiplexer, display, 7segmentdisplay

To multiplex two or more single digit SSD’s, each corresponding pin must be connected to that of the other displays, such as in this schematic.

I’ve accomplished this with 4 displays by using a daughterboard with pin headers, which I then connected to the displays with jumper cables. It was a little messy with so many wires. And I could have easily just used a 4 digit dynamic display.

I need to multiplex two of these single digit displays now. Finding a pre-made dynamic two digit display in the color and size I need (green) hasn’t been easy. So i’d like to just “make” the two digit displays myself. After all, I don’t need just one of these two digit displays for my project, but 4 of these in total. That would be 4 daughterboards.

My idea now is to attach the two displays adjacent to one another on pin headers, then solder cables directly, pin to pin.. This way I don’t need the daughterboards and can save some space.

How would you go about soldering cables to the headers? I’m thinking just wrap the cables once around the header, then heat and bring in solder.. Or is there a better alternative?

Wire wrap also comes to mind, but those factory made wire wrap headers are expensive.

[image]

Comment: Use a header compatible with an IDC cable. Assembling IDC cables is not difficult - if you can't afford the correct tool, a small vise and some care aligning all the bits works quite well.

Answer (score 2):

When I mount up displays like this and it is for a single build type of assembly I use perf board that has plated through holes all over on a 0.1 inch grid. This allows the displays to be soldered in and kept nice and planar with each other.

For wiring I simply use 30awg solid wire-wrap style wire that has kynar type insulation. This is easy to solder directly to the display pins that protrude through the perf board. I would then also install an appropriate dual row pin header, most often a right angle type, to permit connecting a ribbon cable from the board that drives the display. The 30awg wire is also connected to the solder ends of the connector.

The 30awg wires can be routed point to point or can be routed in a neat manner to make the assembly look more professional. When I route the wires in groups I find it convenient to tie the wire bundles through two perf board holes using nylon lacing string or dental floss.